# 数値微分の使い分けについて

Tags: アルゴリズム

差分法では前進差分・後退差分・中央差分とありますが、実装する際にそれらを意識して実装する必要はありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常は、データは十分細かく離散化されている（求めようとする値の周波数よりも高い周波数でサンプリングされている）ので、前進差分・後退差分・中央差分を意識する必要はありません。

もしも意識しなければならないようなデータなのだとすれば、数値微分を用いるのには適しません。